# Align figures in a row using latex

Tags: floats

hi i am using ieee 2 column format .. i am placing 4 figures in a row but why its not aligning properly as you can see right side two figures are slightly above the left ones
[image]
here is my code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{algorithm} 

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[ cc]{\label{Fig5:Fig5a}\includegraphics{z.png}}
\hfill
\subfloat[ccc]{ \label{Fig5:Fig5b}\includegraphics{z.PNG}}
 \caption{vvvvy}
 \label{Fig5:}
\end{minipage}
\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[ccc]{\label{Fig6:Fig6a}\includegraphics{z.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig7}
\subfloat[ccc]{\label{Fig6:Fig6b}\includegraphics{z.PNG}}
 \caption{cccy}
\label{Fig6:}
\end{minipage}
  \end{figure*}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your sample code features 2 [!] `\documentclass` directives. Which one's the real one?

Comment: Use `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` to get top-aligned `minipage`s.

Comment: @Mico sorry it is \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: @Skillmon not working

Comment: Advice of @Skillmon work fine (with `example-image`).  We haven't your real images, so their sizes are unknown to use alo if they maybe have some white space around them.

Comment: i did use same graph image from internet .. it is the same image for 4 figures

Comment: i just need to replace \begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} 
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth} with this \begin{minipage}[t]{<width>} ??

Comment: i just need to replace \begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} 
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth} with this \begin{minipage}[t]{<width>} ??

Comment: is it possible if you placed editable code there ?

Comment: @user12 Just try inserting `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}` instead of `\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}`

Comment: @user12 the `minipage` environment has an optional argument that specifies its vertical alignment. The available options here are `t`op, `c`enter, and `b`ottom. So if you use `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}` you're saying that this one `minipage` should be top aligned and `0.48\linewidth` wide. You'll have to say the same for the other `minipage` (so that must be `t`op aligned as well) for the output to show correctly.

Comment: @Skillmon i tried this but it moves the right side figure to below the left side figures. now it is 2 images in a row

Comment: i edited the code in the question

Comment: @user12 do the figures vary much in size? If so that's the "issue" here. `minipage` with `t`op alignment will align the two boxes at the baseline of the first line, which for graphics included by `\includegraphics` is the bottom of the graphic. You can use `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and then use `\adjustimage{valign=t}{<file-name>}` instead of `\includegraphics` in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to (a) replace *both* instances of `\begin{minipage}` with `\begin{minipage}[t]` and (b) make sure not to leave an all-blank line between the 2 `minipage` environments, as that'll cause a line break (more precisely, in TeX jargon, a paragraph break).

Oh, and while you're at it, please also get rid of noxious code junk such as `\label{Fig7}` and the instruction that defines a macro called `\BibTeX`. Finally, please do keep in mind that nothing good ever comes from loading packages more than once (see: `inputenc`, `babel`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%% Remark: I've streamlined the preamble by removing all 
%% stuff that's of no relevance for the issue at hand.

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % times is obsolete

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{figure}{4} % optional

\begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.49\linewidth} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
  \subfloat[aaa]{\label{Fig5:Fig5a}\includegraphics{Fig5a}}\hfill
  \subfloat[bbb]{\label{Fig5:Fig5b}\includegraphics{Fig5b}}
  \caption{vvvvy} \label{Fig5:}
\end{minipage}\hfill % be sure not to leave a blank line
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
  \subfloat[ccc]{\label{Fig6:Fig6a}\includegraphics{Fig6a}}\hfill
  \subfloat[ddd]{\label{Fig6:Fig6b}\includegraphics{Fig6b}}
  \caption{cccy} \label{Fig6:}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Finally, please do keep in mind that nothing good ever comes from loading packages more than once (see: `inputenc`, `babel`)" - I have seen similar things in multiple instances and if I recall correctly, in most cases (if not all) `inputenc` was among the packages those were loaded twice. I wonder why this happens in similar fashion!

Comment: @Imran - I suspect that the precise reasons for loading some packages more than once (or twice or even more often) can be quite diverse. A common factor among such incidences could be that authors, when they're still fairly new to LaTeX, initially "accrete" various parts of the preamble from diverse sources, e.g., thesis advisor and fellow grad students, and if the code "works", they don't bother to check for redundancies.